# Symfony2 - get EntityManager in Auth Provider

Tags: php, symfony, entitymanager

I've created a custom auth provider. Is there a way to get the entity manager in the auth provider or listener?

I know you can get it in the UserProvider, but the fact is that I want to only flush the user when credentials are right (I authenticate against a windows server Active Directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inject entity manager in service definition, for examle:

```
services:
    wsse.security.authentication.provider:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider
        arguments: ["", "%kernel.cache_dir%/security/nonces", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

And then adjust `__construct` method inside WsseProvider:

```
private $em;

public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $cacheDir, EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    $this->cacheDir     = $cacheDir;
    $this->em           = $em;
}
```

Comment: RIGHT! should've known this. But thanks alot for your quick answer ;)